# How to use Wolframalpha to verify the solution to a DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wolfram-alpha

I would like to find the correct syntax for Wolframalpha so that it will test my solution to a DE. e.g. if I find that $y_p = -t^2 + \frac{3}{2}t - \frac{11}{8}$ and would like to see what that yields when I take $y'' - 3y' -4y$, how could I input this?

I've found the page that will solve DEs for me, but I want to do the work myself and simply find a faster way to verify that my particular form is correct. So far, the only solution I've found is to input $D(Dy) - 3Dy -4y$ where $y = y_p$ and, if I'm lucky, it will provide a simplified form. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't mean to be demeaning, but taking the derivative of a polynomial isn't very difficult, can you not verify by hand? Also you'd ask for wolfram to take the appropriate derivatives.

Comment: Copy and paste is not that hard for plugging in the $y_p$'s.

Comment: @Zach466920 I wrote "e.g." for a reason - simply to clarify the objective. I don't mean to be demeaning, but paying attention to the question and not conflating it with an example isn't very difficult ;D

Comment: @Bye_World what do you write for higher order derivatives? any work around to having to nest D(D(D(D(....)))) ? when I tried d^2/dt^2, it interpreted "d" as days...

Comment: @RaxAdaam Can you not type find nth derivative of $f(x)$? Also, perhaps I feel that not having a real example makes answering the question pointless...

Comment: @RaxAdaam Primes (apostrophes) seem to work too, if that's easier.  Perhaps you should look at a manual for Mathematica.  WolframAlpha tends to accept the same notations.  And if it doesn't you can probably get a cheap version of Mathematica either through your school or from Wolfram directly if you're a current student.  It's much more comprehensive than WolframAlpha.

Comment: @Zach466920 I'm looking for a streamlined way to evaluate any solution in a 2nd - 4th order DE that I can pass on to my students. While I appreciate that a seemingly trivial example can make it unclear *why* I'm looking for this, understanding why is not necessary to answering the question. If, as you say, you feel the example makes it feel pointless, and you can't get past that to be helpful, then just don't answer; someone else will :) If it helps, imagine I want to verify $y_p = -4/10e^{3t}(\cos(t)-3\sin(t))$ in $y'''-y''-3y'-4y$ without wasting time with algebra.

Comment: @Bye_World I tried apostrophes, but it just subbed my $y_p$ and put a prime outside the expression; it wouldn't actually evaluate or simplify the expression. I'm in the middle of a huge move and just thought someone would be familiar & could help quickly. Quick searches for a syntax turned up options for *solving* but not verifying. I want to use the site as a pedagogical tool so that students don't always have to verify everything by hand and can become more confident in their work...

Comment: @Bye_World I just re-attempted with primes, using $x$ and it worked; but now it also seems to work with $t$ - I think perhaps my mistake was writing out the DE and then asking it to evaluate at $y_p$, in which case it would not do any simplification. i.e. $(-t^2 + 3t/2 - 11/8)'' - 3(-t^2 + 3t/2 - 11/8)' - 4(-t^2 + 3t/2 - 11/8)$ worked, whereas ``$y'' - 3y' - 4y$ with $y = (-t^2 + 3t/2 - 11/8)$'' did not. Thanks for pointing me back towards the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste this into Wolfram Alpha:

Simplify  (D[#, t, t] - 3D[#, t] - 4#)& @ (-t^2 - 3t/2 - 11/8 )

The above has the form of $O(y)$ where operator $O$ is defined as $d^2/dt^2 - 3d/dt -4$ which operates on (via the @-sign) the polynomial $-t^2 - 3t/2 - 11/8 $.

To define a function or an operator, use # as the variable and terminate the definition with &.  For example, $m x + b$ becomes (m# + b)&.  It's what is called a pure function.  A better name may be anonymous function.

To define a differential operator, use the derivative operator, which is just a capital D.  For example D[#,x,y]& is a pure function that calculates the second partial w.r.t. x and then y.  You could use it like this

D[#,x,y]&  @  ( x y z - y^2 + z^2 )

Notice the use of square brackets to indicate the argument of the D function.  Notice that I don't use * for multiplication, but you can if you want to.  I like to use parentheses, but you may be able to get away without using them.

Sometimes it helps to put the word "simplify" in front of your expression, so Wolfram Alpha knows what to do with it.

So, back at the top line, we see the & at the end of the pure function.  We see the # sign three places, where the argument of the pure function will be substituted.  We see the @-sign that says to evaluate the pure function "at" the following expression, which is a polynomial in this example and is in parentheses, in this example.

There may be better ways to do this.  The only reason I am using a pure function is that it allows me to insert a complicated argument into each term of the differential operator.

Comment: thank you very much - this is exactly what I had hoped to find and know it would've taken me a *very* long time in any reference. Apologies to the rest of the site - I did not realize there was an exception on syntax questions for Mathematica. I will be sure to post future syntax questions there. All the best -